# Ruby - Chop end of string every time in loop

Tags: ruby, file, loops

I have a problem with my Ruby script. I'm reading text from a file and I want to strip away certain characters.

My file.rb contains this:
`print "Hello!"
print "How are you?"`

It's not very easy to explain so here's the code:

```
File.open("file.rb").each do |line|

line = line[6..line.length]
line = line[0...-1]

end
```

This should return:
`Hello!
How are you?`

However, I get:
`Hello!"
How are you?`

I've done some testing and found out that only the last line in the file has the last character removed from it.

I'd really appreciate some help here.

Thanks,
Reece

Comment: Try this way: `puts line.chomp[7..line.length-3]`. Or `puts line.chomp[7...-1]`.See https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-chomp

Comment: Do you need the text within quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways you COULD do this. I'm going to assume by your current implementation creating multiple temporary strings to get the string that it is not a highly performance critical piece, and using a regular expressions would be perfectly acceptable, likely even an improvement on speed/efficiency.

So long as all the lines in your file follow the pattern where your target string is wrapped in double quotes (`"target string"`), the following could be used:

```
File.readlines('file.rb').map { |line| line[/\"(.*)\"\s?$/, 1] }.compact
```

This would return an array of strings, where each element is a the string you wanted. The `compact` handles lines that do not match, or blank lines by removing `nil` values.

If you do not need to store the values, you can simply implement within a loop:

```
File.open('file.rb').each do |line|
  next unless line = line[/\"(.*)\"\s?$/, 1]

  # Line is now just the string without quotes
  puts line

end
```

Another possible variation could be used in you are concerned matching ONLY print statements (if the file contains other text other than `print` lines)

`^print \"(.*)\"\s?$`